# App rejected (React native android app play store submission)

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, android-permissions, submission

I need help regarding app store submission for my android app, when I try to submit they said like following always.

Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Permissions policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through the policy and make sure your app is in compliance. We've sent more details to admin@xxxxxx.com.

now I had used following permissions only
[image]

FYI,
In my previous submission i had SMSRead and SMS receive permission only 
but i tried to submit app login credentials and also app video uploaded too..

but that case also same issue i had received..

they ask permissions reg following link

https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/

[image]

still they asking same find in above screen shot...

my code is following to remove all permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission  tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"
    />

    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    />

    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"
    />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"
    />

        <uses-permission tools:node="remove" 
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"
        />
        <uses-permission tools:node="remove"
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"
         />

        <uses-permission tools:node="remove"
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"
         />

        <uses-permission tools:node="remove"
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"
        />

         <uses-permission tools:node="remove"
        android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"
         />

        <uses-permission  tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
    />

     <uses-permission  tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
    />

     <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"
    />
```

Comment: Do you have any library dependency where the target version is 15 or lower and the  Manifest contains the permissions for READ_CONTACTS or WRITE_CONTACTS?

Comment: buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
above are the versions for sdk

have u read my code yes it has read and write but i had remove in code see above

Comment: Maybe the part on [implicit system permissions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#implicit_system_permissions) is helpful